# How do I test an externally served app using Testacular + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have an app running on `http://localhost:6543` - it's a Pyramid app.

- This app serves the AngularJS app at /
- This app uses socket.io itself

The question is:  **is it possible to test that application using those tools ?**

I have this in my `scenario.js` file:

```
beforeEach(function() {
   browser().navigateTo('http://localhost:6543/');
});
```

but the moment I launch testacular (with `run` or `start`), I get this error message:

```
Chrome 23.0 registration: should delete all cookies when user clicks on "remove all" button FAILED
browser navigate to 'http://localhost:6543/'
/home/abourget/myapp/jstests/scenarios/registration_scenario.js:9:5: Sandbox Error: Application document not accessible.
```

so I understand the browser doesn't give access to the `iframe`'s document, because it'd be some Cross-Origin violation.

What I tried:

- Proxying to my app using the Testacular web server (with the `proxies` option), but `/` would conflict with Testacular's own serving of its framework.  Also, both apps would eventually try to use `/socket.io` and that would conflict also.
- Doing the reverse (tweaking my app to proxy to Testacular's server), but then, we'd get the same issues with `/socket.io`.

Thanks for these great tools, btw!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of having

```
beforeEach(function() {
    browser().navigateTo('http://localhost:6543/');
});
```

change this to

```
beforeEach(function() {
    browser().navigateTo('/');
});
```

and then in your testacular-e2e.conf.js file add:

```
proxies = {
    '/': 'http://localhost:6543/'
};
```

You might still have other issues, but I can reproduce the "Sandbox Error: Application document not accessible." message with just the [Pyramid Hello World App](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/firstapp.html) and this configuration problem.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, having testacular relay '/' to my app, will break it's own use of /socket.io .. which is kind of shared in this case.

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar problem, and had already proxies and navigateTo('/'). We needed to add some urlRoot to avoid conflicts when loading socket.io. We simply added '/e2e' and that was enough to solve the conflict. Actually, there was a warning message when running testacular for this issue.