# Can do i use testacular to test web pages that are not not on my localhost?

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

Can do i use testacular to test web pages that are not not on my localhost?
The external app was developed using angularJs

In my test i tried doing

```
browser().navigateTo('<test app which is not on localhost>');
```

I cannot verify the url in my test. I get this error :

```
$location.url()

TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'injector'
    at Object.<anonymous> (<localhost path>/angular-scenario.js:25407:30)
```

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13794120/1370576

Comment: No the answer does not help. I get the same error after adding proxies and navigating to root "/" in my code

Comment: I'm having the same issue too, and I already have those.  Mine is saying "no method 'browser'" though.

Answer (score 9):

I encountered the same problem and solved it by adding the following two lines to karma-e2e.conf:

```
proxies = {'/': 'http://localhost:9000/'}; // assume your app is running on port 9000

urlRoot = '/_karma_/';  // important, could be any non-trivial path
```

Comment: Incredibly this worked for me. Does anyone know why?? Is this a bug with the angular scenario adapter for karma?  Thank you very much

Comment: I guess it is because the karma server behaves as a proxy. If you set the proxy for '/', nothing remains for karma (web pages) itself, so you have to set the root for karma on a specific path. You can see that when the browser opens on the karma executor page.